# What is the surrogate liquid for LOx during the preliminary testing of injectors?

Tags: fuel, liquid-fuel, testing, development

Before transitioning to the LOx tests during any new injector development, water is typically used for calculating flow rates, pressure loss, etc.

But testing with water cannot qualify as a suitable substitute for it is highly viscous than LOx. So what is the liquid that is typically suited for these preliminary cold tests?

Comment: Liquid nitrogen is a bit colder (77 to 90 K) and cheap. Argon boils at 87 K.

Comment: I've never heard of anything being used except water.

Comment: @OrganicMarble wouldn't the difference in viscosity translate into difference in flow rate? Or is the discharge coefficient is independent of viscosity?

Answer (score 4):

[Sutton](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6cce/fa84a00b396c5b50b66063772f4851392b8f.pdf) (7th edition, but the only one online) says

> Hydraulic  and  pneumatic  components  (valves,  pipes,  expansion 
>   joints)  can  readily  be  water  flow  tested  on  flow  benches  and
>   corrected  for  pressure  drops  and  density  (and  sometimes  also 
>   viscosity)  to  determine  their  pressure  drop  at  rated  flow.

The fairly in-depth book [The Saturn F-1 Engine](https://books.google.com/books?id=4KW5I4whPXcC&q=water%20flow%20test#v=snippet&q=water%20flow%20test&f=false) mentions only water flow testing for the F-1.  There is a nice picture of an injector test.
[image]

It appears that some [small scale facilities](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/28215/what-is-the-surrogate-liquid-for-lox-during-the-preliminary-testing-of-injectors/28219#28219)(3 lbm/s)  have used LN<sub>2</sub>.

I couldn't find anything on similarity correction for injectors specifically.  [This paper](https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/84280/CAV2009-final11.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) discusses it for turbomachinery:

> Traditionally,  in  scaled  water  flow  turbopump  testing,  it  has 
>   been   considered   sufficient   to   match   flow   coefficient   and
>   cavitation   number,  which   are  the  key  fluid   mechanical 
>   parameters  for  cavitation  similarity.    Strict  Reynolds  number 
>   scaling  is  deemed  unnecessary  in  rocket  turbopump  testing  as 
>   these  pumps  operate  at  very  high  speeds  in  the  fully 
>   turbulent  regime   (Re>10^6 )   where   Reynolds   effects   remain relatively  constant.

Comment: But what is the method to correct for viscosity and density?

Comment: thanks for the links. I too tried to check for similar work before posting here. Seems you too have not come across any such work! Does this all mean that viscosity correction may not be needed given the flow is very turbulent(at very high Re) and inertial forces are the most dominant forces?